# Microsoft Teams: List with voting functionality?

Tags: microsoft-teams, vote, vote-up-buttons

I hope I may ask this in stackoverflow:
I'm looking a way in Microsoft-Team or Sharepoint to build a list of features/functionality where audience can vote up, to sort the list based on user vote. Can you give me hints/ideas?
Many thanks in advance, Steve

Comment: Hi @Steve S, could you please elaborate the issue.

Comment: Hi @Steve S, Just want to know what exactly you are trying o implement in MS-Teams

Answer (score 0):

you can implement your [Microsoft Teams tab using SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-web-part-as-ms-teams-tab). Using SharePoint Framework significantly simplifies Teams tab development process as Teams tabs can be automatically hosted within SharePoint without any need for external services. .